# Spark how to use Pyspark or Scala pipeline in a Java project?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a legacy project written in Java that creates an Apache Spark Dataset, apply a transformation pipeline and collect the results into java collections

```
Dataset<Row>  df = sparkSession.sql("select * from myTable");
// Do transforms on df
df.collectAsList();
```

Doing the transformations in Java is very verbose so I would like to write the transformation pipeline in Pyspark (preferred) or Scala. For example how would I write the following transformation in Pyspark and apply it to my Java dataset ? Also what are the performance consideration between doing the same in Pyspark vs Scala ? I don't want to rewrite the whole program in Python or Scala but just have the transformations written in one of the two language, with both a java dataset as input/output.

```
WindowSpec dt_window = Window.partitionBy("name")
                             .orderBy("date")
                             .rowsBetween(Window.currentRow(), 3);
df = df.withColumn("lastValue",last(df.col("value"),true).over(dt_window));
```